# how access $content array inside a block php?

Tags: nodes

I have created a block and the format of it's content is PHP CODE.

this block is available only full page of node type article.

now in my block , I want to access $content or $page array.

I used global operation such as

```
global $content;
dpm ($content);
```

or

```
global $page;
dpm($page);
```

But both of these blocks return no result.

Please guide me.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Why do you need to access the $content? What data do you need from this variable?

Comment: I want to access and manipulate comment of a current node.

Comment: You need to that in `hook_node_view()` or `hook_comment_view()`, a random block doesn't have access to that data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to extract the comment of a node and put it in a block you can achieve this with a view.

Create a new view who show 'Comments' and create a block.
Now you can add a contexual filter:

Comment: Nid
The node ID to which the comment is a reply to.

After that select 'Provide default value'
and 'Content ID from URL'

Now you can add a 'Validation criteria'
and select 'Content' and check only the content type you want with this block.
now set 'Action to take if filter value does not validate' to 'Hide view'

Now you can add this block to a region in the block page and you have the node's comment displayed in a block.

Let me know if this will work for you ^^

Comment: If I use view to make a block of comments (for special node) , are comment links such as "add new comment" or "sign up or login to write a comment" can be rendered in view result ?

Comment: It is already there in comment section. No need to render those links seprately. What kind of customization you want?

Comment: If you render the entries like 'Comments' you have the default comments display and you can customize that through comment.tpl.php

Comment: I found that module.. I don't know if it can help you... 

https://drupal.org/project/node_comment_block

Comment: thanks. I will try it. but what is your idea about "commentsblock-7.x-2.2.tar.gz" module?

Comment: I never used it. But you can try to install it on your drupal site and see if it's what you need.. From the description it can help you.. Or you can use the view I suggest you ^^

Comment: I checked both modules. node_comment_block doesn't work but In my idea CommentsBlock in https://drupal.org/project/commentsblock is better. I use this module.